# Receive local notification in foreground only

Tags: ios

I know (of course) how to schedule local notifications to fire in background and foreground (both pre iOS 10 and iOS 10 flavors).

However, I cannot find a way to have the local notifications NOT fire in background, but ONLY in foreground. Any hints?

Comment: Don't use local notifications if you just want foreground notification. Just schedule your own timer in your app and display an alert when it fires. Or you could use scheduled local notifications and cancel them in `willEnterBackground`

Comment: That is of course a workaround, I still think local notifications are perfect for scheduling calendar events, ie something should happen April 25 at 16:50... That is very easy with local notifications.

Comment: Another workaround, is to use remote notifications which can be made silent so as to "always" arrive to app (no approval needed), these don't show in home screen.

Comment: @Paulw11 I just found out that good old NSTimer always had an initializer that took an NSDate/Date object. Maybe this is what you meant. It looks like an easy enough workaround. https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer/1415700-init